What is the difference between "the problem about", "the problem of", and "the problem with”?
An acquaintance who is learning English as a second language was asking this question. Even though I am a native English, I am not entirely sure how to answer it.
Here are some examples that I managed to come up with from existing sentences and titles.
Example 1

What's the problem about deciding on a holiday?
What's the problem of deciding on a holiday?
What's the problem with deciding on a holiday?

Example 2

The Problem about Friends with Benefits
The Problem of Friends with Benefits
The Problem with Friends with Benefits

Example 3

As a society, we must address the problem about obesity.
As a society, we must address the problem of obesity.
As a society, we must address the problem with obesity.

Example 4

What is the problem about water in Australia?
What is the problem of water in Australia?
What is the problem with water in Australia?

I think that the difference is a matter of nuance, but I am not entirely sure. What is the difference between "the problem about", "the problem of", and "the problem with"?

The problem of X implies that X itself is a problem - the problem of obesity - or that there are problems involved in defining it accurately - I found books entitled The problem of democracy and The problem of God in modern thought.
The problem with X implies that X has a problem associated with its use - The problem with early cameras; The problem with online ratings.
What's the problem with X? implies that the speaker can't understand why someone finds X difficult - What's the problem with deciding on a holiday?
This Ngram shows that the problem about X is much less common. It could refer to a mathematical problem about a particular topic, or it could mean much the same as the problem with.

The problem about is used in speech, so ngram doesn't help much....+1

There is of course, overlap between "of" and "with," as the source of the problem could also be the best way of naming the topic. E.g. "The Trouble With Tribbles."

Also @Michaelgignac note, "of" doesn't fit idiomatically in certain expressions. We just don't say "what's the problem of X" even if X itself is the problem. And "do you have a problem with me?" suggests that I am myself your problem, but it doesn't use "of." Kate's guidelines above are sound for the examples you gave, but they might not apply in some figures of speech.

All right, I am glad to see an answer. It amazes me how you can have three prepositions and three different meanings!
